# Trigger ListBox SelectedIndexChanged without AutoPostBack = true

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, listbox

I try to accomplish a look a like Combobox in asp (it is a UserControl).

there is a textbox in which you typ in a customername and underneath shows a Listbox with equal Names. There are hidden buttons i trigger with javascript on keycode events.

I want to go through the listbox with up/down arrows and accept my selection on return button, that part works. But i also want to accept a selection if you click an entry with the mouse.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function isKeyPressedA(event)
{
    event = event || window.event;
    if (event.keyCode != 40 && event.keyCode != 9 && event.keyCode != 13){
        document.getElementById('btnADrop').click();            
        bMouseClick = false;
        document.getElementById('Alistbox').AutoPostBack = false;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById('btnEnter').click();
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 40) {
        document.getElementById('btnASelect').click();
    }
}
```

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Atextbox" onKeyUp="isKeyPressedA(event)" Width="250px" autocomplete="off" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="Name oder Email" TabIndex="3" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Inline" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" ID="divADrop" >
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAError" Text="User nicht Vorhanden, bitte E-mail eintragen." style="color:red; display:none; " ></asp:Label>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnEnter">  
                <asp:ListBox runat="server" ID="Alistbox" ClientIDMode="Static" Width="250px" Style="display: none;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Alistbox_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:ListBox>   <%--onchange="javascript: return Changed( this );"--%>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnADrop" Text=""  ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnADrop_Click" Style="display: none;"  />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnEnter" Text=""  ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnEnter_Click" Style="display: none;"  />
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnASelect" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"  OnClick="btnASelect_Click" Style="display: none;" />
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAID"  ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display: none;" ></asp:Label>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAName"  ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display: none;"></asp:Label>            
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnADrop" />
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEnter" />
        </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I know i need `AutoPostBack = "true"` to trigger `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event on mouse click but than i am unable to go trough the list with up/down arrow keys becouse it instantly reloads.

If an entry is accepted it loads the Username in the Textbox `Atextbox`and also to the lable `lblAName` and the selected value into `lblAID`. `btnADrop` loads the listbox entrys on KeyPressed in realtime and `btnEnter` accepts the selected value on return. `btnASelect` just takes the listbox in focus and sets selected index to zero.

Is it possible to accomplish both (Keyboard and Mouse selection)?

Comment: set autopostback true to the textbox and in any case whether mouse selection or keyboard textbox text will be changed then it will postback

Comment: well looks like it works but why ?

Comment: what do you mean by why ?

Comment: more like how but it doesnt work how it should, on mouse click it only works one time and the up/down arrows doesn work anymore

Comment: after postback it's not working ?

Comment: mous selection is working but arrows aren´t becous it triggers when i push down arrow in thextbox then the reload triggers